# How to push a Git repository containing multiple projects

Tags: objective-c, macos, git, github

I have an `Objective-c` project, which I originally started in Xcode3.
This has a `Help Book`, started in a directory at the same level as the project.

I have since added a `Automator Action`, which is a self contained project, but I added a Workspace to include in the Application bundle.

When Xcode introduced Source Control, I started using git in my main project.

I now want to push my Application to github.
If I just push the existing git, the Help Book will be missing, and the build would fail.

What is the best way to proceed so that I can push the Application in a way that other users could build.

**Edit Clarify question**; I have 2 issues:-

1. Ideally the `Help Book` should be saved as part of the `Objective-c` project. This would seem to be a common issue, and is my major concern.
2. The `Automator Action` is a separate project, and could be uploaded separately, but this would not include the Workspace, nor include in the Product Bundle.

Comment: I have edited my answer, basically switching the two repo (one parent, one submodule).

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally the `Help Book` should be saved as part of the `Objective-c` project. This would seem to be a common issue, and is my major concern.

One way would be to record:

- `Help Book` as the main "parent" project, including the `Objective-C` project.
- `Automator Action` as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of `Help Book`, in order for that repo to record the exact SHA1 of `Automator Action`.
  (See [man `git submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule))

  git submodule add /ur/to/Automator%20Action "Automator Action"

You would then need to manage two pushes:

- one done `Automator Action` (possibly from the command line) after adding and committing changes there.
- one from your XCode session, in order to add, commit and push changes from the main project (`Help Book` ): that will also record the exact SHA1 of `Automator Action` used to compile `Help Book`